# mongoDB insert item in Array

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5431f38c4ba4dd20408b0432"),
"UserID" : "1",
"Status" : {

    }
},
"ListFilterType" : 1,
"IssueCategories" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
        "IssueCategoryID" : 2,
        "IssueCagetoryName" : "test",
        "MatchKeyword" : "test",
        "MatchKeywordID" : 2
    }
]
```

}

edit : 
my expactation is like this.

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5431f38c4ba4dd20408b0432"),
"UserID" : "1",
"Status" : {

    }
},
"ListFilterType" : 1,
"IssueCategories" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
        "IssueCategoryID" : 2,
        "IssueCagetoryName" : "test",
        "MatchKeyword" : "test",
        "MatchKeywordID" : 2
    },
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"),
        "IssueCategoryID" : 3,
        "IssueCagetoryName" : "test2",
        "MatchKeyword" : "test2",
        "MatchKeywordID" : 3
    },
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000004"),
        "IssueCategoryID" : 4,
        "IssueCagetoryName" : "test4",
        "MatchKeyword" : "test34",
        "MatchKeywordID" : 4
    }
]
```

i have a type list as "IssueCategories". You can see my mongodb structure above. If root _id = my parameter, I want to add to mongodb. 
I hope I explained right

thanks

Comment: Can you please try again at your document structure since it is presently not valid. Also aside from your title of the question I do not see the question here. Do you want to `$push` to the array of "IssueCategories"?

Comment: yes i do. exactly that @BlakesSeven

Comment: The document structure is still not valid. "I do that, how?" Please show the code you are using right now and what result you expect.

Comment: its full structure. pastebin.com/42ELJiPh @BlakesSeven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push) or [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet) to update document.

`$push` will add all element in `IssueCategories` including duplicates also.
While in `$addToSet` do not insert duplicate elements(object) in array if whole object is present in array.

Using $push:

```
db.collection.update({
    "_id": ObjectId("5431f38c4ba4dd20408b0432") // you can add any other param
}, {
    $push: {
    SCSIssueCategories: {
        "_id": ObjectId("11111111111111111"), //ur id here
        "IssueCategoryID": 3,
        "IssueCagetoryName": "Sözleşme1",
        "MatchKeyword": "abonelik süresi1",
        "MatchKeywordID": 3
    }
    }
})
```

Here is query using `$addToSet`:

```
db.collection.update({
    "_id": ObjectId("5431f38c4ba4dd20408b0432")
}, {
    $addToSet: {
    SCSIssueCategories: {
        "_id": ObjectId("11111111111111111"), //ur id here
        "IssueCategoryID": 3,
        "IssueCagetoryName": "Sözleşme1",
        "MatchKeyword": "abonelik süresi1",
        "MatchKeywordID": 3
    }
    }
})
```

**If single param have different value then it will be inserted in array using `$addToSet`. **